# SVG pattern: relative coordinates using viewbox. issue in firefox

Tags: design-patterns, svg

I have a problem with a pattern that has to have relative coordinates in my SVG. At first, I used patternContentUnits = "objectBoundingBox" which seem to work well all modern browsers. However, I wanted use Batik Rasterizer to allow users to convert SVGs to PDF and/or PNG and Batik Rasterizer doesn't seem to support patternContentUnits = "objectBoundingBox for SVG to PDF conversion.

```
<pattern id="Pattern2" x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
<rect x="0.1" y="0" width="0.33" height="1" style="fill:rgb(39,80,215)"/>
<rect x="0.49" y="0" width="0.47" height="1" style="fill:rgb(11,198,221)"/>
</pattern>
```

As an alternative, I found a internet post in which they used viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none" instead of patternContentUnits = "objectBoundingBox". This solution works well in Chrome, IE9 and also in Batik Rasterizer (!).  However, it  is -not- working in Firefox (14).

I have put a small example online here:
http://mgcv.cmbi.ru.nl/example.svg 
(The first works in Chrome, IE9 and Batik Rasterizer but not in FF14. And the second works well in Chrome, IE9 and FF14 but not in Batik Rasterizer (PDF conversion))

Does anybody have a suggestion? It seems to me that it should be possible to get the viewbox solution working in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in Firefox 17 which is currently in [Beta](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/beta/). See [bug 773467](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=773467) and [bug 773595](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=773595) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have downloaded FF17 and in there it indeed works like it should. Is there some kind of work-around to get it working in older versions? Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Other than avoiding objectBoundingBox, no I don't think so.